# Convert a dict that simulates a tree into lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, tree

I have a dict like this:

```
{
1: {
   3: {
      1: {c:32},
      2: {c:12}
      },
   4: {c: 66}
   },
2: {
   3: {c: 1},
   5: {c: 2}
   }
}
```

How can I elegantly unroll this tree to get:

```
[
[1, 3, 1, 32],
[1, 3, 2, 12],
[1, 4, 66],
[2, 3, 1],
[2, 5, 2]
]
```

This structure can be arbitrarily deep.

EDIT - I don't care about the order of the output. 'c' is a count of the times a particular sequence of integer was seen.  So in this case, [1, 3, 1] was seen 32 times.

The exact format isn't so important, it's the technique I am after.

Comment: How do you decide on the order? And what's `c`?

Comment: Based on what you got the output?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga edited

Answer (score 6):

#### Recursion:

```
def flatten(d, prefix=()):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from flatten(v, prefix=prefix+(k,))
        else:
            yield list(prefix + (v,))
```

#### Iteration:

```
from collections import deque

def flatten(d):
    queue = deque([[[], d]])
    while queue:
        prefix, node = queue.popleft()
        if isinstance(node, dict):
            queue.extend([(prefix + [k], v) for k, v in node.items()])
        else:
            yield prefix[:-1] + [node]
```

*Note:* It's relatively easy to blow the stack using recursion in Python.  If your data is huge, i.e. deeper than `sys.getrecursionlimit()`, then you should prefer the breadth-first solution - this may consume a lot of memory but it will not [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion).

Answer (score 4):

```
def unroll(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for l in unroll(v):
                yield [k] + l
        else:
                yield [v]
```

You'd call it like

```
list(unroll(d))
```

For your input I got

```
[[1, 3, 1, 32], [1, 3, 2, 12], [1, 4, 66], [2, 3, 1], [2, 5, 2]]
```

Comment: Nice, you could shorten the for .... yield to a yield from, for python3.3+, (edit: as wim has done in their post)

Comment: Thank you, I have to learn about yield. My structure is kinda huge and I am getting memory errors. I am not using list(...) but am trying to just iterate over the result and print it out (for now). Is there a reason that

for x in unroll(d): print(x) would not work?

Comment: @TonyEnnis No reason that wouldn't work.  If your structure is really big you might have more success treating it like depth first search